# Convert complicates string into integer?

Tags: javascript, parsing, parseint

I've retrieved a string into a variable with innerHTML method. The string is:

```
£&nbsp;125.00
<!-- End: pagecomponent/pricesplit -->
```

I only want the 125.00 part. Is it possible to use the parseInt() method to convert this into an integer? Alternatively what can I do to extract the 125.00 part?

Thanks

Comment: '£&nbsp;125.00'.match(/\d+/ig);

Comment: No, you want to use `parseFloat`

Comment: I've added description why you cant use `parseInt` and how you can extract only the numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a regular expression to remove anything but digits and periods, and then run `parseInt` on the remaining string:

```
parseInt(yourString.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''), 10);
```

Test the regex [here](http://regexr.com?33fkb). Here's a breakdown:

`/.../` is just the syntax you use for wrapping a regular expression. Ignore these.

`[...]` creates a character class.

`^` when placed at the beginning of a character class, it negates everything inside.

`\d` any digits

`.` a literal period. It does not need to be escaped inside a character class - outside it would mean "any character" and need to be escaped.

So `/[^\d.]/` means "match anything that is not a digit or period", and subsequently replace it with an empty string.

If your number might include significant digits after the decimal, such as `125.50`, you should use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: I don't think that would be a reliable match :-) Think of digits not occuring in the price, or a price without decimals…

Comment: @Bergi price without decimals would work fine. Digits outside of the number would cause problems, OP would have to know the format of his strings to see if he needs to work around this. Dot is not in `\D`, according to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). "`\d` is short for `[0-9]`."

Comment: Ah, you've fixed `[\D.]` to `[^\d.]` - I should've also read your text :-)

Comment: @Bergi yes `[\D.]` would not work because the `\D` was ruining the or clause :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I wasn't even aware of javascript regular expressions before. This really does indeed fit what I need, however I still need to wrap my head around what all the \ and / means in the expression

Comment: @user208709 i have added a breakdown to the answer. see my edit.

Comment: @jbabey thanks for the breakdown, that helped me wrap my head around it IMMENSELY! Thank You! and it works

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value using regular expression. Here is an example:

```
var str = '£&nbsp;125.00<!-- End: pagecomponent/pricesplit -->';
parseInt((/\d+/).exec(str)[0], 10);
```

Or if you also want to get the zeroes:

```
(/\d+\.\d+|\d+/g).exec(str)[0]
```

You can't get it directly using `parseInt` because when a string does not start with number `parseInt` does not work.

Comment: I believe only allowing digits will strip the `.`, giving you `12500` instead of `125`.